# Extract a certain kind of word from an unformatted string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

The given string is inside a .txt file where there are other similar lines of this format but different.

```
line = "39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010"
```

- Type: {Sedan, coupe, hatchback, station, SUV}
- Transmission: {Auto, manual, steptronic}
- stock: Combination of letters and numbers NOT ending with “km” Drivetrain {FWD,RWD,AWD}
- Status: {Used, new}
- Fuel Economy Similar to: 5.5L/100km
- format car_maker: {Honda, Toyota, Mercedes, BMW, Lexus}
- Model: Any text that doesn’t match any of the other criteria in this table
- Year: Any year
- Trim: any two letters acronym
- set_of_features: Any set of features inside curly parenthesis

My solution:

```
model = /[^ #{carmaker}.to_s#{drivetrain}.to_s#{stock}.to_s#{year}.to_s#{trim}.to_s#{setOffeatures}.to_s#{fueleconomy}.to_s#{type}.to_s#{transmission}.to_s#{km}.to_s]/.match(line)
puts model returns
u 
x 
w
```

I need to extract prius for model, but I need a general pattern matching that can match any kind of model, ie camry, altima, fiesta etc depending on what the file contains.
I tried lots of ways, but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you format your question?

Comment: I am new here, i'm not sure how to do that to make it more readable and explain my question properly. sorry

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Comment: the input is the string type line and from there I extracted various forms of substring such as trim, type, km, year etc but for MODEL I can't seem to work it out, since the question is asking for any text that doesn’t match any of the other criteria in this table which contains type, km, stock, status, model, maker, year, setOfFeatures,trim.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the below code snippet.

```js
const filterString = (file, string) => {
    let result = file.split(',').filter(word => word !== string).join(',')
    return result
}

// In your case you would read this in from the file system
// Using Node it would be the fs library, fs.readFileSync(path, utf8)

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

let file = `39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
39km,Sedan,Manual,4738B,AWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,prius,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
`

let result = filterString(file, 'prius')
console.log(file, result)
```

Comment: but actually the LINE is going to be in a file where there could be many other lines among which it might not only be prius but other values as well.

Comment: So you can see from the above you can still accomplish this, I created a function that you can call with the file, and item to be removed. You may be reading it from the file system first if so if you are using Node then the fs library would help there.